# How to add a 404 error code when route does not exisit?

Tags: php, routes, http-status-code-404, phalcon

How can I throw a 404 error code when a route does not exist?

In phalcon after you set up your routing information - is there a way to check to see if a route coming in (from the user) matches any of the routes in your routes list? Then, if the route does not exist, throw a 404 error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
public function main()
{
    try {

        $this->_registerServices();
        $this->registerModules(self::$modules);
        $this->handle()->send();

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        // TODO log exception

        // remove view contents from buffer
        ob_clean();

        $errorCode = 500;
        $errorView = 'errors/500_error.phtml';

        switch (true) {
            // 401 UNAUTHORIZED
            case $e->getCode() == 401:
                $errorCode = 401;
                $errorView = 'errors/401_unathorized.phtml';
                break;

            // 403 FORBIDDEN
            case $e->getCode() == 403:
                $errorCode = 403;
                $errorView = 'errors/403_forbidden.phtml';
                break;

            // 404 NOT FOUND
            case $e->getCode() == 404:
            case ($e instanceof Phalcon\Mvc\View\Exception):
            case ($e instanceof Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher\Exception):
                $errorCode = 404;
                $errorView = 'errors/404_not_found.phtml';
                break;
        }

        // Get error view contents. Since we are including the view
        // file here you can use PHP and local vars inside the error view.
        ob_start();
        include_once $errorView;
        $contents = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        // send view to header
        $response = $this->getDI()->getShared('response');
        $response->resetHeaders()
            ->setStatusCode($errorCode, null)
            ->setContent($contents)
            ->send();
    }
}
```

If you are using the [Micro](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/micro.html#not-found-handler) component you can use this:

```
$app->notFound(
    function () use ($app) {
        $app->response->setStatusCode(404, "Not Found")->sendHeaders();
        echo 'This is crazy, but this page was not found!';
    }
);
```

Of course you can use the suggestions that others posted regarding the .htaccess file, but above is how you do it in Phalcon without touching anything else.

There is also a new feature coming down the pipeline, regarding a default error handler that would process errors in Phalcon (or overriden if necessary).

Credits to Nesbert for the [gist](https://gist.github.com/3701633#L88)

Comment: this seems like what i need, let me try it out. Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: thank you, it worked. I had to make some changes so it could work with the multimodel file structure i have. http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/0.5.0/reference/applications.html#multi-module

Answer (score 5):

Once you have your 404 page setup, all you need to do is send visitors to incorrect url’s to this page. To do this just add the following line to your .htaccess file :

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

You can place the 404 error template anywhere you want. For example you could place all error messages in a folder called errormessages

```
 ErrorDocument 404 /errormessages/404.php
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the default HTTP 404 Error while executing a PHP script:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
```

But remember this is meant to be the first thing you send to the client.

If you wnt to customize your web server default PHP Error, that depends on the software. Its easy to find the filde apache uses, for instances, to display this kind of error.